# R extract labels from a rda data frame

Tags: r

I am looking at some data downloaded from [ICPSR](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/35206/versions/V4) and I am specifically using their R data file (.rda). Beneath the column name of each data file, there are some descriptions of the variables (a.k.a labels). An [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uvis.png) is attached as well.

I tried various ways to get the label including base::label, Hmisc::label, labelled::var_label, sjlabelled::get_label and etc. But none worked.

So I am asking any ideas on how to extract the labels from this data file?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: cold you add a `dput` of your data?

Answer (score 1):

this could work using `purrr`

```
#load library
library(purrr)

#get col n
n <- ncol(yourdata)

#extract labels as vector
labels <- map_chr(1:n, function(x) attr(yourdata[[x]], "label") )
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (I am working with ICPSR 35206):

```
attributes(yourdata)$variable.labels -> labels
```

Make sure that your attribute referring to the labels is actually called "variable.labels".